# Cannot find namespace NodeJS

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, socket.io, ionic2

I'm using Ionic2 and socket.io

When I do `ionic serve` I get this error in the terminal:

```
TypeScript error: typings/globals/socket.io/index.d.ts(357,30): Error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'NodeJS'.
TypeScript error: typings/globals/socket.io/index.d.ts(739,28): Error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'NodeJS'.
```

Node version is 4.2.6

My typings.json looks like this:

```
{
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {},
  "globalDependencies": {
    "es6-shim": "registry:dt/es6-shim#0.31.2+20160602141504",
    "socket.io": "registry:dt/socket.io#1.4.4+20160317120654",
    "socket.io-client": "registry:dt/socket.io-client#1.4.4+20160317120654"
  }
}
```

If I open `typings/globals/socket.io/index.d.ts` (with sublimeText) I see this :
[image]

As you can see also sublimeText complains about NodeJS namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar issue with a Node Typescript project.  Turns out I just didn't have Node set as a global dependency.

```
typings install dt~node --global --save-dev
```

shortcut:

```
typings i -GD dt~node
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide your `typings.json`?

Try to update to the latest commit `7de6c3dd94feaeb21f20054b9f30d5dabc5efabd`

I also had same problem (with different namespaces), update fixed it.

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/socket.io-client/socket.io-client.d.ts

**EDIT:**
Try:

```
"socket.io": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/socket.io/socket.io.d.ts#7de6c3dd94feaeb21f20054b9f30d5dabc5efabd",
"socket.io-client": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/socket.io-client/socket.io-client.d.ts#7de6c3dd94feaeb21f20054b9f30d5dabc5efabd"
```

Comment: I tried to update my typings.json file as you suggested but it still doesnt work. I've edited the question, look at the picture I uploaded.